# SSH tunnel only works on loopback interface

Tags: ssh, tunneling

What i am trying to do:
I want to connect to an ubuntu server (server A) thats behind a NAT from the internet.
Ive got an ubuntu server (server B) with its own ip adress/domain. I want to make server A to connect to server B and estabilsh a ssh tunnel so anyone can connect to server B and use services on server A.

What i have tried so far:

basicly on server A i have used this:
`ssh -N -R *:[PORT]:localhost:[PORT] [usrname]@[domain]`

server B accepts the connection and a test where i do:
server A
`sudo nc -l [PORT]`
server B
`sudo nc localhost [PORT]`

works.

The problem comes when i try to connect from my pc (windows) to server A via server B.
I use ncat.exe for this:
server A
`sudo nc -l [PORT]`
pc:
`.\ncat.exe [domain] [PORT]` does not work, `refused connection`

It also works when i:
server B
`sudo nc -l [PORT]`
pc
`.\ncat.exe [domain] [PORT]`

So firewalls are not the problem. So it must be that on server B ssh only listens for the loopback interface, since that worked. But in the ssh doc it says

> By default, TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to the loopback interface only. This may be overridden by specifying a bind_address. An empty bind_address, or the address ‘*’, indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces. Specifying a remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's GatewayPorts option is enabled (see sshd_config(5)).

But i actually used * for the bind adress, shouldnt it listen to all interfaces?

Note that every time i wrote [PORT] its the same port.

Answer (score 1):

Ive got it. What i failed to recognize is that it is not up to the client if the server actually forwards the port for remote users. On server B i had to edit sshd_config and change GatewayPorts to yes. Its right in the text i copy-pasted here and now i feel stupid.